# If statement in shell-script only half-working

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I've been trying to write a script to rotate my monitor, I'll then assign it to a keyboard key.
I've been fairly successful in making it rotate once, however when I run the script again, it doesn't rotate.
I'm probably missing something obvious as I'm new to this.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
rotation="xrandr -q --verbose|grep LVDS1|cut -b37-42"
if [ "$rotation" = 'normal' ] ;
then
  xrandr -o inverted
else
  xrandr -o normal
fi
```

I followed the instructions found here, but had to modify them a bit:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1675299

I'm running Arch Linux 3.19.3-3-ARCH if that matters.

Comment: Slightly cleaner: `rotation=$(xrandr -q --verbose | awk '/LVDS1/ {print $5}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way tou get the result of your command and put it in your variable `$rotation`:
You should replace

```
rotation="xrandr -q --verbose|grep LVDS1|cut -b37-42"
```

with

```
rotation=$(xrandr -q --verbose|grep LVDS1|cut -b37-42)
```

UPDATE:
The explication is that the differents quotes expand commands and variables in different ways:

- simple quotes `'` don't expand anything:

  ```
  TEST="hello world"
  echo '$TEST'
  ```

  will output

  > $TEST
- double quotes `"` will expand variables:

  ```
  TEST="hello world"
  echo "$TEST"
  ```

  will output

  > hello world
- And backticks ``` will expand commands:

  ```
  TEST="pwd"
  echo `$TEST`
  ```

  will output

  > /path/to/current/dir

But to get the result of a command you can also use `$(myCmd)`.